# Paper undefined in JS function using Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

Alright, so I am having a bit of trouble with Raphael and automatic updating of elements.

I've got a file called objects.js which looks something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('ikoner'), 600, 200);
    pump = paper.circle(50,100,50);
    pump.data("id","pump");
    pump.data("tag",':="output".tag5:');
}

function objectFill (table) {
    paper.forEach(function(e){
           var tagValue = e.tag.innerHTML;
           var tagId = e.id.innerHTML.trim();
           if (tagValue == 0) {
                paper.getById(tagId).attr({fill:"white"});
           }
    }
}
```

On my main page I've got a script which then calls objectFill on a certain interval, and updates the fill color of my objects. 
Now to the problem; when I run the page I get the error that paper is undefined in objectFill. How do I make sure that objectFill will be able to find the paper? I've also tried declaring it outside like:

```
var paper;
window.onload = function() {   
    paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('ikoner'), 600, 200);    
}
```

But I do not get that to work either. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: put objectFill function inside the onload function, so they both have the same scope.

Comment: Tried this but now my other HTML documents seems to be unable to see the objectFill function, it threw an error that objectFill is undefined.

Comment: Put all of the functions inside the onload function then :).